# @ModelAttribute for Jersey similar to Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jersey

I wonder whether *jersey* has something like *Spring MVC* can offer to pass several query parameters inside a one. When we need to group several params in *Spring MVC*, we can use `@ModelAttribute` and have these query params in URL listed as `?name=SomeName&city=SomeCity` ... Then we just create a POJO that contains these fields. Does *jersey* have similar functionality? Using a json is  unacceptable for my case cause I'm modifying an old API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with `@BeanParam` starting with JAX-RS 2.0. See a sample [here](https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2014/07/21/new-in-jax-rs-2-0-beanparam-annotation/).

Comment: Thanks! That's it. Works fine. I tried BeanParam. But the reason for it not working was the fact that I missed @QueryParam on top of the fields inside the POJO. In spring you can just leave them without any annotations and that will work fine and the values will be parsed as query parameters. In any case, it's not much harder with jersey.

Comment: That is because BeanParam can have inside headers, PathParam etc. From this point of view BeanParam is superior to ModelAttribute from spring -rest